# Is it possible to play a game which you bought on Xbox One on Windows 10, without having to pay for it?

Tags: xbox-one, windows-10

I've bought a game on Xbox One. The game is also available on Windows 10, but I want to know if it's possible to install the game I bought for Xbox One on my Windows 10 and play it for free ?

Comment: What game is it?

Comment: @TimmyJim Ori and the Blind Forest: Definitive Edition

Comment: @The_Diver: Please see http://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-titles/ori-blind-forest-de-windows-10-faq. As far as I can tell, this is *not* an Xbox Play Anywhere title so you will need to purchase it again on your Windows 10 device; however, cross-play is supported allowing for saves and achievements to sync across your computer and Xbox One as long as you're signed into the same Microsoft account on both devices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For this to work with a game, it needs to be part of Microsoft's [Xbox Play Anywhere](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/games/xbox-play-anywhere) program.  That link will take you to the program's official page, with a list of current and upcoming Play Anywhere games.  Unfortunately, if the game isn't on that list then you will have to purchase it on your PC to play it there.

Comment: Hence why I asked... what game? Some of the games I know that are part of this program are Recore, Gear of War 4, and Astroneer.

Comment: Also the content you buy for Killer Instinct